# Is it possible to present a View when a timer reaches a certain number in SwiftUI?

Tags: timer, swiftui

I'm new in SwiftUI, but I need to know if it is possible to show/present a View, when a 5 second timer reaches 0.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a code to run some time in the future in `.onAppear`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showSecondView = false

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if showSecondView {
                Text("Second view")
            } else {
                Text("First view")
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
                self.showSecondView = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The rest of the code depends on *how* you want to display another view. Here is the solution to replace a view with another.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here's an example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isPresented = false
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
                self.isPresented.toggle()
            }
        }, label:  {
            Text("Start")
        })
            .alert(isPresented: $isPresented) { () -> Alert in
                Alert(title: Text("Complete!"))
        }
    }
}
```